# From tensorboard, how to explain tensor_content?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensor

When I use tensorboard, I find something interesting. And I have explained a little, but I want to know more.
The problem is show as below,
I define a tensor which equals `[-1, 28, 28, 1]`, and use tensorboard to display the node, there are some attributes.

```
dtype {"type":"DT_INT32"} 
value {"tensor":{"dtype":"DT_INT32","tensor_shape":{"dim":[{"size":4}]},"tensor_content":"\\377\\377\\377\\377\\034\\000\\000\\000\\034\\000\\000\\000\\001\\000\\000\\000"}}
```

Look at the `tensor_content`, the binary of 377 is `011 111 111`, we need last 8 bits, so `377,377,377,377 = 111......111 (32 bits)`, which equals `-1` in decimal, and `034 = 000 101 100`, we need last 8 bits `00101100`, so `034,000,000,000 = 00101100...(... means 24 bits of 0)`, and we should look it from right to left, so it equals 28, the remaining 28 and 1 are the same.

And I want to ask whether my explanation is right. And if it is right, why don't use 377 (3 3 bits-binary) rather than 15,15 (2 4 bits-binary)? Can anyone provide me statement by official materials?

Comment: Could you try https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print, which would save you tons of time interpreting these encoded numbers.

Comment: For some reason, integers are stored in octal (base 8) in the graph definition - no idea why. The quickest way to convert to decimal is to use the same function that TF uses under the hood -
 i.e. np.fromstring(b"\377\377\377\377\034\000\000\000\034\000\000\000\001\000\000\000",dtype=np.int32)